# How to convert configuration file in XML format to normal .conf file

Tags: java, xml, configuration

the content of my xml is like:

```
<keyspaces>
    <keyspace name="book_ks">
        <consistencySettings>
            <table name="default" read="ONE" write="ONE" batchStatementType="LOGGED"/>
            <table name="book" read="ONE" write="ONE" batchStatementType="LOGGED"/>
        </consistencySettings>      
    </keyspace> 
    <keyspace name="class_ks">
        <consistencySettings>
            <table name="default" read="ONE" write="ONE" batchStatementType="LOGGED"/>
            <table name="class" read="ONE" write="ONE" batchStatementType="LOGGED"/>
        </consistencySettings>      
    </keyspace>
</keyspaces>
```

originally, I load the xml element in java by using

```
final Element keyspace = doc.getElementViaXpath("../keyspaces");
final NodeList keyspaces = keyspace.getElementsByTagName("keyspace");
```

then read the elements by using a for loop.

how to convert this format of xml configuration to a normal configuration file like:

```
ks_names = book_ks,class_ks
default_book_properties = default,one,one,logged
book_properties = book,one,one,logged
```

is there any better way to do that? how should I design the property file, and how to read the properties automatically in a loop, or something like that?
cause the there could be more keyspaces to be added to the list. I dont want to change the code to read the properties manually.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `.properties` files. [Oracle Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html) and [file reading example](http://crunchify.com/java-properties-file-how-to-read-config-properties-values-in-java/) will help You.